# Ubuntu 13.04 doesn't see my 2TB hard drive

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, gpt, fdisk

I have a small problem. I switched today from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 13.04 on my home PC. I have installed 3 hard drives - 250GB, 500GB and a 2TB. On the 250GB I have installed the system - clean installation, formatted it. To make sure I don't screw with my other data I disconnected other drives (and switched places).
Now, after installation when I boot to Ubuntu the system finds the 500GB drive and I can access all the data, but the 2TB drive is not present. In the "Disks" that drive is marked as empty. But when I booted the ActiveBoot to check it - all the data is fine and I can access it.

Any ideas how can I access that 2TB from system level? It holds lots of important data and I don't have enough space to backup it and format it again...

EDIT (sorry for polish language, but I'm just used to localized system):

```
sudo fdisk -lu
[sudo] password for marcin: 

Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
głowic: 255, sektorów/ścieżkę: 63, cylindrów: 30401, w sumie sektorów: 488397168
Jednostka = sektorów, czyli 1 * 512 = 512 bajtów
Rozmiar sektora (logiczny/fizyczny) w bajtach: 512 / 512
Rozmiar we/wy (minimalny/optymalny) w bajtach: 512 / 512
Identyfikator dysku: 0x0004c4b4

Urządzenie Rozruch   Początek      Koniec   Bloków   ID  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   488396799   243947521    5  Rozszerzona
/dev/sda5          501760   488396799   243947520   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
głowic: 255, sektorów/ścieżkę: 63, cylindrów: 60801, w sumie sektorów: 976773168
Jednostka = sektorów, czyli 1 * 512 = 512 bajtów
Rozmiar sektora (logiczny/fizyczny) w bajtach: 512 / 512
Rozmiar we/wy (minimalny/optymalny) w bajtach: 512 / 512
Identyfikator dysku: 0x3c51041e

Urządzenie Rozruch   Początek      Koniec   Bloków   ID  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   976771071   488384512    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

UWAGA: Na '/dev/sdc' wykryto tablicę partycji GPT (GUID Partition Table)! fdisk nie obsługuje GPT. Należy użyć GNU Parteda.


Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000394706432 bytes
głowic: 256, sektorów/ścieżkę: 63, cylindrów: 242250, w sumie sektorów: 3907020911
Jednostka = sektorów, czyli 1 * 512 = 512 bajtów
Rozmiar sektora (logiczny/fizyczny) w bajtach: 512 / 4096
Rozmiar we/wy (minimalny/optymalny) w bajtach: 4096 / 4096
Identyfikator dysku: 0x00000000

Urządzenie Rozruch   Początek      Koniec   Bloków   ID  System
/dev/sdc1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partycja 1 nie zaczyna się na granicy bloku fizycznego.

Disk /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt: 249.8 GB, 249800163328 bytes
głowic: 255, sektorów/ścieżkę: 63, cylindrów: 30369, w sumie sektorów: 487890944
Jednostka = sektorów, czyli 1 * 512 = 512 bajtów
Rozmiar sektora (logiczny/fizyczny) w bajtach: 512 / 512
Rozmiar we/wy (minimalny/optymalny) w bajtach: 512 / 512
Identyfikator dysku: 0x00000000

Dysk /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt nie zawiera poprawnej tablicy partycji

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-root: 232.6 GB, 232616099840 bytes
głowic: 255, sektorów/ścieżkę: 63, cylindrów: 28280, w sumie sektorów: 454328320
Jednostka = sektorów, czyli 1 * 512 = 512 bajtów
Rozmiar sektora (logiczny/fizyczny) w bajtach: 512 / 512
Rozmiar we/wy (minimalny/optymalny) w bajtach: 512 / 512
Identyfikator dysku: 0x00000000

Dysk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-root nie zawiera poprawnej tablicy partycji

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-swap_1: 17.2 GB, 17179869184 bytes
głowic: 255, sektorów/ścieżkę: 63, cylindrów: 2088, w sumie sektorów: 33554432
Jednostka = sektorów, czyli 1 * 512 = 512 bajtów
Rozmiar sektora (logiczny/fizyczny) w bajtach: 512 / 512
Rozmiar we/wy (minimalny/optymalny) w bajtach: 512 / 512
Identyfikator dysku: 0x00000000

Dysk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-swap_1 nie zawiera poprawnej tablicy partycji
```

Comment: Is the drive mounted and showing empty, or will it not mount?

Comment: It won't mount. In the "Disks" it's empty, I can only format it. It's like this:
http://turkut.mydevil.net/Duperele/Screenshot%20from%202013-08-28%2022:18:05.png

Comment: Run `sudo fdisk -lu` and edit the results into your question

Comment: I upticked it, but I thought I should also say ^^ this

Comment: Edited the post adding the results. Maybe it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem can be correctly found in the output of `sudo fdisk -lu`. In fact, it goes as far as to simply tell you.

Polish (original):

> UWAGA: Na '/dev/sdc' wykryto tablicę partycji GPT (GUID Partition Table)! fdisk nie obsługuje GPT. Należy użyć GNU Parteda.
>
> Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000394706432 bytes głowic: 256, sektorów/ścieżkę: 63, cylindrów: 242250, w sumie sektorów: 3907020911 Jednostka = sektorów, czyli 1 * 512 = 512 bajtów Rozmiar sektora (logiczny/fizyczny) w bajtach: 512/4096 Rozmiar we/wy (minimalny/optymalny) w bajtach: 4096/4096 Identyfikator dysku: 0x00000000
>
> Urządzenie Rozruch Początek Koniec Bloków ID System /dev/sdc1 1 4294967295 2147483647+ ee GPT Partycja 1 nie zaczyna się na granicy bloku fizycznego.

English (translated):

> **NOTE: '/dev/sdc' found GPT partition table (GUID Partition Table)! fdisk does not support GPT. You must use GNU Parted.**
>
> Disk /dev /sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000394706432 bytes heads: 256, sectors/track: 63, Cylinders: 242250, total sectors: 3907020911 Units
>   = sectors, or 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical) in bytes : 512/4096 Size/O (minimum/optimal) in bytes: 4096/4096 disk identifier: 0x00000000
>
> Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System /dev/sda1 1 4294967295 2147483647 + ee GPT Partition 1 does not start at the border of the physical block.

The is the important line is bolded. You are using the newer GPT partitioning system, and you may need to install the gparted package.

> gpt is the newer partitioning scheme than MBR which has been the partition layout since PC hard drives in mid 1980's.
>   gpt is required if drive is over 2TiB or about 2TB and is recommended for any drive that does not have Windows as Windows only boots with gpt partitioning if using UEFI not BIOS.

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1952953&p=11820622#post11820622)

Comment: Installing `gdisk` won't help the kernel find the partitions on the disk. That said, there may be something wrong with the GUID Partition Table (GPT) on the disk, and `gdisk` can help diagnose that. In particular, run `sudo gdisk /dev/sdc` and then type `v` to verify the disk. Also, type `ls -l /dev/sdc*` to see what partitions the kernel is detecting. Edit your original post with the `gdisk` and `ls -l` output for interpretation.

Comment: Sorry, i meant the gparted package, which is what i use to access my 2TB External Hard Drive.

Comment: The `gdisk`, `parted`, and GParted tools are all used to enable users to examine and manipulate partitions, but the kernel itself has its own means of reading GPT (and other partition tables). A failure such as the one Marcin reports could be a failure of the kernel or (much more likely) a damaged partition table. To identify and repair such damage on a GPT disk, `gdisk` is the best tool for the job; but you'll need to know how to use it to do so. See http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html for details, or post back with the output of `gdisk`'s `v` command for help.